# JQuery get part of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a function that is changing pages without reloading. In this function I get back a string. This string contains the whole html value. This is an example of the string value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
(Some meta data and links to css files)
</head>
<body>
   <div id="1">some content</div>
   <div id="2">some content</div>
   <div id="3">some content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I only want to get the content of the div with the id "2". How can I achieve this since this is in a JS string variable?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to handle this server side any only send back that div in the first place?  Less traffic from server to client too.  Wins all round.

Comment: Or use jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) passing fragment url selector  `$('#container').load('scriptURI #2');`. BTW, your question is really badly asked, post the relevant code you use to change the page without reloading...

Comment: @JamesThorpe Sounds like OP is using ajax request: `I use a function that is changing pages without reloading`

Comment: what i understand is that you want only to GET the data ? 
Just use $('#2).text() as a classic selector ? 
Else use the .substring(), or .slice() methods of String object if you already have the whole html code to extract the content (because of <div id="x"> is a known lenght)

Comment: @A.Wolff Indeed.  I'd still prefer to only send back the data actually needed from the server than send everything and process it further on the client, even if it is a single liner in jQuery.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Ya you are correct in most cases

Comment: Just a sidenote: `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")` from [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You can create a jquery object using string value and then find div with id=2 to get the text of  div.

```
var stringVal = "your html string";
var $div = $(stringVal).find("div#2");
var text = $div.text();//will get only text part
var html = $div.html();//will get text as well as all child elements
```

Comment: This is indeed giving me the value of the div. But the div also includes a few divs inside of it and they are all gone, but the content is still there.

Comment: if you want div inside div then use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: Yes thats it, thanks. Was afraid I had to make my whole project again :)

Comment: happy to help you :)